# What is "energy" in computer vision

Tags: algorithms, graphs, image-processing, digital-image-processing

I keep seeing the term "energy" used in computer vision literature, specifically when speaking about Image Segmentation. For example on this page on [Graph-Cut](https://profs.etsmtl.ca/hlombaert/energy/).

I'm just wondering if someone could give me a layman's explanation of what "energies" are. I'm pretty new to the subject, and I'm not finding anything online explaining what it is.

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: One starting point for reading more might be the sources referenced at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_cuts_in_computer_vision (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_minimization)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think "energy" in this context has a specific meaning. It is just an arbitrary objective function depending on the problem.